# Python Queue.Queue and deque consistency?

Tags: python, queue

Given this code...

```
import Queue

def breadthFirstSearch(graph, start, end):
q = Queue.Queue()
path = [start]
q.put(path)
visited = set([start])
while not q.empty():
    path = q.get()
    last_node = path[-1]
    if last_node == end:
        return path
    for node in graph[last_node]:
        if node not in visited:
            visited.add(node)
            q.put(path + [node])
```

Where graph is a dictionary representing a directed graph, eg, {'stack':['overflow'], 'foo':['bar']} ie, stack is pointing to overflow and foo is pointing to bar.

Why am I not getting the same result when I replace Queue.Queue with deque from collections to increase efficiency?

```
from collections import deque

def breadthFirstSearch(graph, start, end):
q = deque()
path = [start]
q.append(path)
visited = set([start])
while q:
    path = q.pop()
    last_node = path[-1]
    if last_node == end:
        return path
    for node in graph[last_node]:
        if node not in visited:
            visited.add(node)
            q.append(path + [node])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Queue.Queue` version uses FIFO while your `deque` version uses FILO. You should use `path = q.popleft()` instead to fix this.

Note that `Queue.Queue` internally uses an underlying `deque` to represent the queue. For more info, see the [relevant documentation](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/Queue.py#l208) (see `_get` method)

Comment: Thanks it works, just to be sure, using deque in this situation is more efficient right?

Comment: @Clay Yes because `Queue` itself uses `deque` (see edit), `Queue` has the advantage of being thread safe however

Comment: I did not know that, thank you for the insight, I can see the improvement in my program using deque because my graphs are so large.

Comment: @Clay A small thing you can also do is make each path a tuple eg. `path = (start, )` and also `q.append(path + (node,))` which would be slightly faster than lists

Comment: `deque` is also thread-safe for `append()` and `popleft()`. "Deques support thread-safe, memory efficient appends and pops from either side of the deque with approximately the same O(1) performance in either direction." https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#deque-objects